# Set GridPanel height dynamically?

Tags: extjs

Inside a viewport, how do I set the GridPanel height dynamically?

Comment: You'll probably need to add a little more detail.

Comment: Yeah please tell us where do you use the grid ? inside a window or in a viewport ? what layout do you use ?

Comment: Inside viewport, I have to show 4 grids in wizard form one by one(here i am using card layout)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you can set the grid height, then either use scroll or paging for navigation.